# What does the sentence 'de rham cohomology is functorial on the category of continuous maps between open sets in Euclidean spaces' mean?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, homotopy-theory, de-rham-cohomology

From the book from Calculus to Cohomology, intro remark in Chapter 6 Homotopy. My query is what does the word functorial mean?

Comment: It's a standard concept in category theory. Basically, it is the structure preserving morphism between categories.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the book by Madsen and Tornehave, they are referring to the result they prove in Theorem 6.8 (ii). The general concept of "functor" can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor . In Th 6.8 the authors prove de Rham cohomology gives a sequence of functors between the category of open sets of Euclidean space, whose morphisms are homotopy classes of maps, and the category of abelian groups.